# Why does $a=v/t$ not work for light?

Tags: kinematics, photons, speed-of-light, acceleration

if acceleration = velocity/time and light takes approx. 8 minutes to reach from the sun to earth doesn't that mean light is accelerating at 37,500,000 m/s^2 ?

Comment: It's not velocity you use, it's *change* in velocity.  As the light did not change speed, there's no acceleration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pertinent equation is normally
$$a=\frac{dv}{dt}\ \ .$$
If you're taking a non-calculus-based course in physics,
$$a=\frac{v}{t}$$
might be used, but it's only applicable in a situation where an object is undergoing constant acceleration, and the object's velocity is zero at $t=0$.

Light doesn't accelerate at all on its way between the Sun and the Earth, so $a=v/t$ isn't applicable to the situation at all.

$d = v t$ does apply to light travelling between the Sun and Earth.